# How can I use a negative lookahead in an anchored regular-expression pattern?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

My web-application allows users to specify custom URI path components which comply with the following restrictions:

- All characters must be lowercase.
- Be at least 2 characters long.
- First character must match `[a-z]`.
- The last character must match `[0-9a-z]`.
- All other characters must match `[0-9a-z_\-]`.
- The `-` and `_` characters must not exist as a consecutive run of 2 or more.

  - i.e. The string must not contain `--`, `__`, `_-`, or `-_`.

I've implemented the first 5 rules in a regular-expression easily enough:

```
^[a-z][0-9_a-z\-]*[0-9a-z]$
```

...however I don't know how to implement the last rule in a single regex.

I thought I'd start by just trying to change the regex so it won't match `--` (as in `a--b`) - and I was thinking it could be a negative-lookahead, as it's asserting that that regex does not contain `--` ([right?](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)):

> Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called “lookaround”, are zero-length assertions just like the start and end of line, and start and end of word anchors. [...]  The difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match. That is why they are called “assertions”. They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not

But adding `(?!\-\-)` to the regular expression ([on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BdJvlb/1)) in various spots, or as a lookbehind `(?<!\-\-)` does not cause strings like `a--b` to *not-match*.

i.e. all of these patterns match `foo--bar` when it shouldn't.

```
(?!\-\-)^[a-z][0-9_a-z\-]*[0-9a-z]$

^(?!\-\-)[a-z][0-9_a-z\-]*[0-9a-z]$

^[a-z](?!\-\-)[0-9_a-z\-]*[0-9a-z]$

^[a-z](?!\-\-)(?:[0-9_a-z\-]*)[0-9a-z]$

^[a-z][0-9_a-z\-]*(?!\-\-)[0-9a-z]$

^[a-z][0-9_a-z\-]*(?<!\-\-)[0-9a-z]$
```

Comment: The lookahead could be `^[a-z](?!.*[_-][_-])[0-9_a-z-]*[0-9a-z]$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Okay, but how do I use that as part of the larger regex?

Comment: I have updated the comment

Comment: @Thefourthbird That worked, thanks (post it as an answer?) - but why is the `.*` part necessary to make it work when surely just "`[_-][_-]`" is needed to match invalid substrings?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Right before you posted your comment I got it working using `^[a-z](?:(?![\-_][\-_]).)*[0-9a-z]$` (but I'll still use yours as it's simpler), though I don't understand why my version requires the extra group around the lookahead but yours doesn't.

Comment: @Dai That last pattern also works, and that technique is knows as a tempered greedy token. But the single lookahead is enough in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the negative lookahead right after matching a-z at the start of the string.

As you don't want to match any combination of - and - you can use 2 character classes `(?!.*[_-][_-])`

As the `[_-][_-]` part can occur anywhere in the string, you can precede it with `.*` optionally matching any character.

If you omit `.*` the assertion only runs on the current position, which in this case would be after matching the a-z at the start of the string.

```
^[a-z](?!.*[_-][_-])[0-9_a-z-]*[0-9a-z]$
```